# How do you code so that when you press the button once it actuates a servo and when you press the button again it moves the servo back?

Tags: button, arduino, servo

I’m try to get it to work but it turns when I press the button and goes back when I let go of the button at the moment

```
//sketch created by Akshay Joseph          follow me on Instagra:  five_volt_player

include<Servo.h>
Servo Myservo;
int pos=0;
void setup()
{
   pinMode(2,INPUT);
   Myservo.attach(3);
}

void loop()
{
   if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){
    Myservo.write(180);
  }
  else

 Myservo.write(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many times a second it is "checking" to see what it should be doing. Right now your code says, "If at this exact moment I am pushing the button, then go to 180. Otherwise (If I'm not pushing the button) go to 0."

There are a few different ways to do what you're trying to do. Keep experimenting!

I would probably create a variable at the top of your code before void loop(), something like this:

```
int motorState = 0;
```

Then have the Myservo.write(motorState) each time just inside void loop().

For the if else statement in, I would say (unformatted) something like: if the button is pressed and motorState==180, then motorState==0.
Else if button pressed and motorState=180, then motorState==0.

Comment: I did this but I think I did it wrong

Comment: #include<Servo.h>
Servo Myservo;
int pos=0;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  Myservo.attach(3);
}

int Myservo.write(0);
{
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
  }
  else

  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
}

void loop()
{
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){
    Myservo.write(90);
  }
  else
    
 Myservo.write(0);

}

Comment: sorry that looks wrong ill just post a second question thank you